# javascript access class factory from class instance

Tags: javascript, generics

Is it possible to access the factory that created current instance from the same instance?

for example:

```js
class Vect {}
class DVect extends Vect{}

const calcFunc = (inst:Vect|DVect) =>{
  let constructorParams = ...
  return new inst.Factory(...constructorParams)
  //note - Factory is not a real method
}

console.log(calcFunc(new Vect))
// will log a Vect instance

console.log(calcFunc(new DVect))
// will log a DVect instance
```

here I would expect a `Vect` to be returned if I passed to `calcFunc` a `Vect` and `DVect` if I passed `DVect`

so, is it possible in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [`.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#description) property that's on almost every object in JS:

```js
const calcFunc = (inst /*: Vect|DVect */) => {
  let constructorParams = //...
  return new inst.constructor(...constructorParams)
}
```

(Edge case: objects created by `Object.create(null)` won't have a `.constructor` property. But objects created by doing `new Vect`, `new DVect`, `new` of any `class {...}` should all have a `.constructor`.)